# Help Unmouting disk if UUID is mounted until a Specific Time

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, mount, diskutil

Every morning I have the same routine.

I come into work and plug in my peripherals including my Time Machine Backup. I have my Time Machine scheduled to only run one daily backup at 3:30pm.  I would like to run a script or a .plist LaunchDeamon to check all inserted external hard drives automatically and unmount if the

```
UUID = 32E89C07-FFDB-36F3-8CE8-5DC0560AFEC4
```

And then mount it at 3:15pm.  I just do not want my drive to be plugged in all day just to use it for 30 mins to back everything up.

I know this could all be resolved if I just manually plug in the drive at 3:15. However, some days I am in a meeting or away from the desk and what-not.

I was able to find documentation on how to auto eject the device at a specific time so I do not have to remember to safely remove the drive.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
            <string>com.diskejector.Backup</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/sbin/diskutil</string>
            <string>unmountDisk</string>
            <string>32E89C07-FFDB-36F3-8CE8-5DC0560AFEC4</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
                <integer>16</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>45</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I would like some help with auto launching a .sh script that could also include the previous code I have to eject the drive at the end of the day.

Comment: You could use `cron` to automatically execute the .sh script. In fact, if you use cron, i don't think you'll even need those plist or sh files. You can directly specify the `diskutil`'s mount and unmount command in cron and make it run daily at specific time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shell script needed if you use two launch agents.

You need the UUID of your Time Machine backup drive:

```
diskutil info $VolumeName | grep "Disk / Partition UUID:"
```

Replace `$VolumeName` by the actual volume name of your TM drive. If the name contains spaces use double quotes (e.g. "Time Machine backup drive".

Create two files usr.tmvolume.unmount.plist and usr.tmvolume.mount.plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents/:

```
nano ~/Library/LaunchAgents/usr.tmvolume.mount.plist
```

with the content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>usr.tmvolume.mount</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/diskutil</string>
        <string>mount</string>
        <string>$UUID</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>15</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>15</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

and

```
nano ~/Library/LaunchAgents/usr.tmvolume.unmount.plist
```

with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>usr.tmvolume.unmount</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/sbin/diskutil</string>
        <string>unmount</string>
        <string>$UUID</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>30</integer>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>15</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>45</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Replace $UUID in both plists by the UUID of your Time Machine volume found previously.

Load both plists with:

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/usr.tmvolume.*
```

Now the TM backup  drive will be unmounted at 8:30am, mounted at 3:15pm and unmounted again at 3:45pm. Adjust the dates as needed.

Comment: Awesome!  This is what I was looking for.  I just need to make sure I plug in before 8:30!  Thanks!